# Identity is trying to duplicate the email property when I insert a user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-identity

So I have an asynchronous Task method where type T = `ActionResult` to create a new user to be stored in the database (DBMS = SQL Server). This used to work perfectly before without any errors but all of a sudden it starts breaking when it gets to this point in execution:

```
 var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I have reverted everything to the working version on Git but still no luck.

What could be the problem and how can I get around this?

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = model.UserName,
            firstName = model.firstName,
            lastName = model.lastName,
            Email = model.email,
            cellNo = model.cellNo,
            DateCreated = DateTime.Now
        };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            //  util.Log(User.Identity.GetUserId(), 5, "Account - Added a user ( " + model.UserName + " ) to the system");
            return RedirectToAction("SuccessfullyAddedNewUser", "Users", model);
        }
        else
        {
            AddErrors(result);
        }
    }
    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}

//Users controller action method to get redirected to once new user has been created successfully
// GET: /Users/SuccessfullyAddedNewUser
public ActionResult SuccessfullyAddedNewUser(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    return View(model);
}
```

**Model: ApplicationUser**

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{

    [Required]
    [StringLength(11, MinimumLength = 11)]
    [Display(Name = "Cell Number")]
    public string cellNo { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50), MinLengthAttribute(3)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string firstName { get; set; }


    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50), MinLengthAttribute(3)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string lastName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Created")]
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DefaultValue(false)]
    public Boolean MustResetPassword { get; set; }

    //Concatenates the first and last name
    public String getFullName()
    {
        return firstName + " " + lastName;
    }
}
```

Exception:

> Exception: Message = "An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."
>
> Inner Exception: The column name 'email' is specified more than once in the SET clause or column list of an INSERT. A column cannot be
>   assigned more than one value in the same clause. Modify the clause to
>   make sure that a column is updated only once.  If this statement
>   updates or inserts columns into a view, column aliasing can conceal
>   the duplication in your code.

But when I check my code, I only specify email once only.

Comment: Add error you get to the question.

Comment: have you updated the identity package/

Comment: **`it starts breaking`**. Too bad this is not a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. No way to tell what could be the problem based on what is currently shown.

Comment: @Harold_Finch add a break point to the `Console.Write...` bit of your catch and run in debug mode. You can copy and paste the exception detail from the breakpoint

Comment: @Harold_Finch `IdentityUser` already has an `Email` property. Your `ApplicationUser` is duplicating that property with `email` regardless of case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IdentityUser` already has an `Email` property. Your `ApplicationUser` is duplicating that property with `email` regardless of case.

Remove the duplicated property

```
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
public string email { get; set; }
```

from `ApplicationUser` or override it with

```
[Display(Name = "Email Address")]
public new string Email { get; set; }
```

if the intention was just to add the display attribute.

Comment: @Harold_Finch not a problem. Just goes to show that when a complete example is provided it makes it easier for the community to provide you with targeted answers.

Comment: That it did. The reason why my initial question was a bit brief is because some people feel as though it gets too lengthy and are lazy to read throughout.. But thanks for your valued effort.

Comment: @Harold_Finch People will be upset if you don't provide an MCVE. It really captures it all. Have you bothered looking at [what that means](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Your question should be long enough to reproduce the error (Verifiable), no more (Minimal), no less (Complete). If you truly do that, I will be shocked if someone complains about length.